# Test PHP Script Online

Tags: php, testing, ide

Last Month [codepad.viper-7.com](http://codepad.viper-7.com/) was down and a lot of [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) answers with code pasted there became broken include some of mine. When it was back all scripts where lost.

Am looking for a free anonymous alternative to [codepad.viper-7.com](http://codepad.viper-7.com/) where i can test `php` scripts with minimal restriction (`fopen`, `curl` , `mb_strlen` etc); on different versions.

There so many of them recommended here but its difficult to find suitable replacement to [codepad.viper-7.com](http://codepad.viper-7.com/)

Simple Testing Script

```
<?php
   echo strlen(file_get_contents("http://google.com"));
?>
```

Output

- [codepad.viper-7.com](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JvuOqy)  = 43736
- [sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) = disabled
- [writecodeonline.com](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) = disabled
- [exorithm.com](http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/sandbox) = 43736 but non-anonymous func, print_r  etc disabled
- [codepad.org](http://codepad.org) = failed
- [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/WRcC9t) = disabled
- [coderun.com](http://www.coderun.com/ide/) = 43736 but Only PHP Version 5.3.1 supported
- [codeanywhere.net](https://codeanywhere.net/) = Registration Required
- [eval.in](http://eval.in/5093) = Forbidden syscall socketcall
- [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/JVoIh) = failed

**Question:**

Is there any anonymous alternative with minimal restrictions ?

Comment: shows research effort, useful and clear folks!

Comment: @Barmar length of response of google.com

Comment: @Prasanth This is why http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/172224

Answer (score 3):

You can try [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/). But be aware that `http://google.com` is redirected to `https://www.google.com`, so `file_get_contents` will return `301 Moved`.