# regex to scrape data from web page

Tags: php, regex

I tried to scrap data from web page using regex but it gives DOM warning. So I want to know, is it possible for regex to scrape date, review, rate value from this page?

> http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80

Here is with DOM:

> https://eval.in/143074 give error.
>
> This works for smaller code : https://eval.in/143036

Is it possible using regex?

```
<?php
$html= file_get_contents('http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80');

$html = escapeshellarg($html) ;
$html = nl2br($html);

$classname = 'rating-qualifier';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}


$classname = 'review_comment ieSucks';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

$meta = $dom->documentElement->getElementsByTagName("meta");
echo $meta->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
?>
```

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986359/test-php-script-online

Comment: try running your code on your local machine, what error do you get there ?

Comment: Using only "regular" regex this is only possible if the site structure is guaranteed to never change and you know it exactly, because `HTML is no regular language` http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: @aelor: it gives error for non formed html code similar to `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 756 in F:\wamp\www\htdocs\thenwat\yelp.php on line 23`

Comment: I can suppress these error using `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`. Solution above is taken from one of your reply only on different thread

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: thanks, any hint for this?

Comment: @Programming_crazy don't do much php over here, but this looks promising: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/2186023

Comment: Now that all `eval.in` demo links are dead, this page is missing its [mcve].  Please statically provide sample input in your question body.